# JavaScript For loop in If Else statement response

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I have used `if-else` statements in `for` loop, but I always receive the response as **Country count in Canada value**, other countries (India, UK) show the value 0. What is the issue and why am I not receiving counts for other countries?

```
fLen = jArray.length;

for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {        

    if (jArray[i]['territory']=='India') {
        var india = jArray[i]['country_count'];
    }
    else {
        var india = '0';
    }

    if (jArray[i]['territory']=='United Kingdom') {
        var uk = jArray[i]['country_count'];
    }
    else {
        var uk = '0';
    }

    if (jArray[i]['territory']=='Canada') {
        var Canada = jArray[i]['country_count'];
    }
    else {
        var Canada = '0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare your `var`s outside from your `if...else` blocks

Comment: Doesn't the interpreter put the `var` declarations at the beginning of the current scope because of *hoisting* ?

Comment: Big salute to those who were able to understand the question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to following

```
var india = '0', uk = '0', canada = '0'; // put your variables outside for loop
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {


    if (jArray[i]['territory']=='India') { // only set value in loop
        india = jArray[i]['country_count'];
    } else if (jArray[i]['territory']=='United Kingdom') {
        uk = jArray[i]['country_count'];
    } else if (jArray[i]['territory']=='Canada') {
        canada = jArray[i]['country_count'];
    }
}
```

**Reasoning** - Whenever your loop runs it sets the value for the matched condition and sets everyone else to '0'. When it happens for the last value in array, only the matched condition will be having some value and rest all will be 0 because of the if..else condition. Hence, move the initial values outside the loop and use if.. else if in the for loop to check for the match.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `india`, `uk`, `Canada` are unique and overriden over the iterations of the `for-loop`. So at the end, they will only match the last data (`i=fLen-1`).

You have to create a result array, such as `india = []`, then fill `india[i]` in your for loop.